# Use Web Components with Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am currently trying reusing Web Components in a Vue Component. The Web Components use `template` for formatting the output, but when i place it in the Vue Template, it will be removed from the DOM or compiled by Vue. The Point is: Web Components need this `template` element for working.

Is there anyway to tell Vue to ignore this `template` element while compiling?

Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to tag the element with [v-pre](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre) which prevents Vue from compiling it.

From the official documentation:

```
<span v-pre>{{ this will not be compiled }}</span>
```

Comment: Well that is only for normal tag. What i want is to be able to use v-pre for `template` tag